# How to upload screenshots in play store listing in play console through python & official APIs

Tags: python, automation, google-api, google-play-console, google-developers-console

I am going to launch an app in play store. It will be available in many languages

Issue is that for each language, I want to upload separate name, short description, long description, feature image, mobile screenshots, tab screenshots. And manually uploading all this to play console for each language is headache for me

I was able to figure out this code:-

```
import argparse
import sys
from apiclient import sample_tools
from oauth2client import client

TRACK = 'alpha'  # Can be 'alpha', beta', 'production' or 'rollout'

# Declare command-line flags.
argparser = argparse.ArgumentParser(add_help=False)
argparser.add_argument('package_name',
                       help='The package name. Example: com.android.sample')


def main(argv):
  # Authenticate and construct service.
  service, flags = sample_tools.init(
      argv,
      'androidpublisher',
      'v2',
      __doc__,
      __file__, parents=[argparser],
      scope='https://www.googleapis.com/auth/androidpublisher')

  # Process flags and read their values.
  package_name = flags.package_name

  try:
    edit_request = service.edits().insert(body={}, packageName=package_name)
    result = edit_request.execute()
    edit_id = result['id']

    listing_response_us = service.edits().listings().update(
        editId=edit_id, packageName=package_name, language='en-US',
        body={'fullDescription': 'Dessert trunk truck',
              'shortDescription': 'Bacon ipsum',
              'title': 'App Title US'}).execute()

    print ('Listing for language %s was updated.'
           % listing_response_us['language'])

    listing_response_gb = service.edits().listings().update(
        editId=edit_id, packageName=package_name, language='en-GB',
        body={'fullDescription': 'Pudding boot lorry',
              'shortDescription': 'Pancetta ipsum',
              'title': 'App Title UK'}).execute()

    print ('Listing for language %s was updated.'
           % listing_response_gb['language'])

    commit_request = service.edits().commit(
        editId=edit_id, packageName=package_name).execute()

    print 'Edit "%s" has been committed' % (commit_request['id'])

  except client.AccessTokenRefreshError:
    print ('The credentials have been revoked or expired, please re-run the '
           'application to re-authorize')

if __name__ == '__main__':
  main(sys.argv)
```

But unfortunately I am unable to figure out how to upload screenshot & related images.

Below is the relevant link, but I failed to figure out python code for it
https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/rest/v3/edits.images/upload

How to upload screenshot images through python?

Thanks & Regards

Comment: You have specified the correct API to use. What does "I was unable to move ahead from here" mean? Edit your question to show the code you wrote and clearly describe the problem.

Comment: @JohnHanley Thanks for the reply. 
You are absolutely correct. Let me rephrase the question & its content